# Lock http requests for exclusive resource access

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a service which looks locally in a sql table for a value. If the value does not exist it is doing a remote call. If there is a value returned from the remote call then this value is added to the local sql table.

I have notified Unique Index exceptions in the log file that the string value XXX already exists.

To me that means that the following happened:

```
Request1_localSqlCheck
Request1_remoteCheck
Request2_localSqlCheck
Request2_remoteCheck
Request1_AddValueLocallyIfRecievedByRemote
Request2_AddValueLocallyIfRecievedByRemote // Same value Added here causes exception.
```

I want to make all 3 steps atom and lock it:

```
Lock
{
Request1_localSqlCheck
Request1_remoteCheck
Request1_AddValueLocallyIfRecievedByRemote
}
```

Will this work putting a lock around these 3 method calls?

Comment: Locks don't cross process boundaries. If this service runs on a farm or in multiple workers, a lock won't suffice.

Comment: The remote service runs in the clound but restricted to ONE instance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Mutex` to block the code execution until the server returns the value.

For example:

```
    private readonly Mutex m = new Mutex();

    public int ThreadSafeMethod() {

        // you can do this immediately to skip the mutex
        if (Request1_localSqlCheck == 1) return 1;

        m.WaitOne();

        try {
            // check again
            if (Request1_localSqlCheck == 1) return 1;

            Request1_remoteCheck
            Request1_AddValueLocallyIfRecievedByRemote

        } finally {
            m.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }
```

Just to be clear, it can be really problematic if this code is called very frequently because it will slow down all the other thread that will have to wait for the mutex.

IMHO, if the "unique" error is not a big deal, I think you can stick with it; it can be boring, but sometimes is better to try and fail than wait for mutex release and slow down everything.

Comment: I did a try/catch on the duplicate key exception and just return the existing value from the sql table.